# why I got crash when I use object_getIvar to find NSURL object 's instance variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

This is a simple test program,It's will crash at object_getIvar(url, ivars[I]);crash info is that Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200001d80)

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"dasadas"];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
    unsigned int count;
    Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList([NSURL class], &count);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        id obj = object_getIvar(url, ivars[i]);
        [result addObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }
    free(ivars);


//    @autoreleasepool {
//        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
//    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS when attempting to retrieve value using object\_getIvar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309532/exc-bad-access-when-attempting-to-retrieve-value-using-object-getivar)